# Converting argv arguments to int

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, argv, atoi

I have tried atoi, strol, and stoi but none of them are working for me. I've even tried to subtract '0' from the char which I heard should work but that threw an error too. atoi gives me a Segmentation Fault, strol won't compile, and stoi gives me an std logic error. here is my entire program as of right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       const int size = 199;
       int counter = 1;
       int primeAry[size];

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // creates an array of prime numbers
   {
      if (isPrime(i))
      {
        primeAry[counter] = i;
        counter++;
      }
   }
   for (int j = 1; j <= argc; j++) // finds prime numbers by index of args and displays them
   {
      if (j == 1)
         cout << "Last name is " << argv[j] << endl;
      else
      {
         int temp = atoi(argv[j]);
         cout << temp << " th prime number is " << primeAry[temp] << endl;
      }
   }

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int num)
{
   if(num <= 1)
      return false;
   else if (num <= 3)
      return true;
   else if (((num % 2) == 0) || (num % 3) == 0)
      return false;

   int i = 5;
   while((i*i) <= num)
   {
      if ((num % i == 0) || ((num % (i + 2)) == 0))
         return false;
      i = i + 6;
   }
   return true;
}
```

And here is the result I get:

```
Last name is smith
1 th prime number is 2
2 th prime number is 3
3 th prime number is 5
Segmentation Fault
```

I've been working on this forever and I've searched every forum that I could find but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

> Segmentation Fault**

You get segmentation fault when you pass `NULL` to `atoi`. This is happening because your loop bounds are incorrect. This:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= argc; j++)
```

should instead be

```
for (int j = 1; j < argc; j++)
```

In C, you should treat *all* loops with `<=` terminating condition with extreme suspicion. More often than not that's where the bug is hiding.

Comment: Thank you! I figured that it would be something ridiculously simple.